# Are Catholic schools run by seculars a post-Vatican II novelty?

Tags: catholicism, united-states, vatican-ii, lay-ministry, education

Are Catholic schools run by seculars (non-religious laity) a post-Vatican II novelty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Jamie Faser Arthur, “[What Is the Lived Experience of Laywomen Who Serve as Catholic Elementary School Principals in Their Roles as Faith Leaders?](http://scholarworks.gsu.edu/eps_diss/86)” (Georgia State University, 2012), 11:

> In **1965** indicate there were 13,292 schools serving 5.6 million students with
> **religious orders positioned in nearly 100% of administrative positions** and 58% religious
> as full-time professional staff (Guerra, 1991). However, 2009-2010 figures show a sharp
> decline with only 7,248 Catholic schools, 2.2 million students, and only 3% religious
> orders serving as full-time professional staff (NCEA, 2010). […] the closing of nearly 50% of its schools and 97% fewer religious serving the
> remaining ones

<sup>(my **emphases**)</sup>

[image: Transition in Staffing from Religious to Lay during the period of 1965 to 2010]